# Swift / Adding objects to NSMutable Array

Tags: arrays, swift

Im new to Swift and Im having a hard time understanding why this is not working - I've tried many different combinations of this through examples on stackoverflow and my variable "collections" still comes out empty (see last line) so I'm guessing I'm missing a small (but important) detail. Appreciate any help!

```
class CollectionsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var collections = NSMutableArray()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SDK.sharedInstance()
            .getAuthenticatedUserBoards(withFields: ["id", "name","url","description","image"],
                success: { data in
                    guard let myData = data?.parsedJSONDictionary["data"] as? [[String: Any]]

                    else {
                        return
                    }

                    for item in myData {
                        self.collections.add(item)
                    }
            }, andFailure: nil)

            print("collections.....\(collections)") 
            //Output: collections.....() 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are actually _getting_ any data in your callback? Have you tried printing out what your callback returns? You might be getting an empty `NSMutableArray` because _there is nothing to add_.

Also, using `NSMutableArray` in Swift is _usually_ a code smell. You should be using native array types, like `[Int]`, or if you really don't know what kind of data you're getting, `[AnyObject]` (which is equivalent to NSMutableArray)

Comment: You need to print `collections` inside the success handler, not outside.

Comment: hi @rmaddy but I need to use the collections data in another func so I need this array to have all the data?

Comment: @PedroCastilho yes 100% getting data! im able to print all the items within the loop.

Comment: That function does have all of the data but just at a later time. You need to understand how asynchronous calls work. What do you need to do with the data once it is loaded?

Comment: @rmaddy i'm trying to use that data in an UITableView.  Here is the func, my output is 0 in here.     ----   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        print("collections ---- \(collections.count)") //Output: 0
        return myBoards.count
        
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading of the data is asynchronous. Since your goal to load your table view after the data loads, you need to call `reloadData` on your table view at the end of the `success` block. But UI calls must be made on the main queue so you should use `DispatchQueue` to do this.

Here is what you need:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SDK.sharedInstance()
        .getAuthenticatedUserBoards(withFields: ["id", "name","url","description","image"],
            success: { data in
                guard let myData = data?.parsedJSONDictionary["data"] as? [[String: Any]]

                else {
                    return
                }

                for item in myData {
                    self.collections.add(item)
                }
                print("collections.....\(collections)") 

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }, andFailure: nil)
}
```

Since you are currently updating `self.collections` in the background, there is a small chance your UI on the main queue will see a partially up-to-date set of data. So I would recommend one further change:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SDK.sharedInstance()
        .getAuthenticatedUserBoards(withFields: ["id", "name","url","description","image"],
            success: { data in
                guard let myData = data?.parsedJSONDictionary["data"] as? [[String: Any]]

                else {
                    return
                }

                var list = NSMutableArray()
                for item in myData {
                    list.add(item)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collections = list
                    print("collections.....\(collections)") 
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }, andFailure: nil)
}
```

This ensure the main `collections` property is only updated on the main thread.

I also suggest you use a Swift array of a specific type instead of using an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Oh my gosh! thank you!! reloadData was exactly what I needed to add!!

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `getAuthenticatedUserBoards` is making some sort of asynchronous call to an API. Since we're not sure how long that call is going to take, the task is placed on a background thread while the rest of the app's tasks continue to run on the main thread. Your print statement is one of those tasks that will run while the API call is happening in the background. In essence, the print statement executes before anything inside of the `getAuthenticatedUserBoards` is completed.

The list of collections should be printed directly after the for loop and before the end of the closure. You can verify the order in which the different tasks are completed by placing print statements at various different points within your function - you should be able to see that your current print statement will print before any other statements that you place inside of the closure.

Comment: Thanks so much for this clear answer! Rookie mistake re: the print statement! When I put this statement inside my success handler, I definitely do see the boards. However, the board still comes out empty in my next override func. So what can I do to actually collect this data properly (and globally) so I can used this populated data anywhere? Thank you!

Comment: No problem - for the 2nd part of your question, @rmaddy's answer has what you need